# hibernate envers does not get triggered for jpa queries

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I am using hibernate envers to audit events and it works fine along with Spring Data JPA Repository  when i invoke repositoy.delete() or repository.save()

But If I write a jpa query and delete the entity using a query  , then it hibernate envers audit listener does not get invoked.

I read that hibernate envers will not trap native query - But will it not work for hibernate/jpa queries as well ?

Thanks
Lives

Comment: I think your problem could be this: For query based data manipulation no lifecycle callbacks will be triggered and no cascades will be triggered on the level of the persistence context. This means, entity listeners listening to an @PreUpdate event will not get notified. Also any cascade operations - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173273/how-to-override-a-delete-method-on-a-spring-data-crudrepository?noredirect=1#comment35489769_23173273

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139856/hibernate-envers-doesnt-write-audit-records-for-createquery-executeupdat) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370596/work-around-for-envers-auditing-for-bulk-update) post, envers is not triggered in your situation.

Also check out [this](https://community.jboss.org/thread/149545) related question in the JBoss forum